# Coin counter adding double values for each exact coin

Tags: c#

Im doing a C# program that is suppose to take an amount from 0-99 (amount of change given back) and from that the program should put the change in the correct positions. A example is if I enter:

Amount of change given back: 68

it should read as:

Quarters 2

Dimes    1

Nickles  1

Pennies  3

I am using a Windows form application in visual studios 2015.

Whenever i enter the amount of 1, it should be 1 penny but it gives it 2, same for dimes nickles and quarters. anything else it works just fine.

This is what my code looks like:

```
private void calcButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    //declare variables

    const int QUARTERS = 25;
    const int DIMES = 10;
    const int NICKELS = 5;
    const int PENNIES = 1;
    int changeVal = 0;

    //validations
    if (int.TryParse(changeTextBox.Text, out changeVal)){
        if (changeVal > 0 && changeVal < 100){
            //calcs each value with the remainder operator divided by each change amount
            int quarterVal = changeVal / QUARTERS;
            int dimeVal = ((changeVal % QUARTERS) / DIMES);
            int nickelVal = (((changeVal % QUARTERS) % DIMES) / NICKELS);
            int pennyVal = ((((changeVal % QUARTERS) % DIMES) % NICKELS) / PENNIES);

            //if statements to put each coin in each specific value variable
            if (changeVal == QUARTERS){
                quarterVal++;
                changeVal = changeVal - QUARTERS;
            }
            else if (changeVal == DIMES){
                dimeVal++;
                changeVal = changeVal - DIMES;
            }
            else if (changeVal == NICKELS){
                nickelVal++;
                changeVal = changeVal - NICKELS;
            }
            else if (changeVal == PENNIES){
                pennyVal++;
                changeVal -= changeVal - PENNIES;
            }

            //display

            quartersLabel.Text = quarterVal.ToString();
            dimesLabel.Text = dimeVal.ToString();
            nickelsLabel.Text = nickelVal.ToString();
            penniesLabel.Text = pennyVal.ToString();
        }

        //error message
        else{
            MessageBox.Show("You have to enter a numeric value greater than 0 and less than 100");
        }


    }
    //error message
    else{
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value");
    }
}
```

If you can tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be very helpful!

Comment: did you try to debug it? I think that will give you the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing your ChangeVal to the face value of the coins.   and then Incrementing it when they are equal,

This Section only runs when your changeVal is equal to the facevalue of the coin
hence 1, 5, 10, 25 all produce a double count.  Just remove the section below.

```
      if (changeVal == QUARTERS)
                {
                    quarterVal++;
                    changeVal = changeVal - QUARTERS;
                }
                else if (changeVal == DIMES)
                {
                    dimeVal++;
                    changeVal = changeVal - DIMES;
                }
                else if (changeVal == NICKELS)
                {
                    nickelVal++;
                    changeVal = changeVal - NICKELS;
                }
                else if (changeVal == PENNIES)
                {
                    pennyVal++;
                    changeVal -= changeVal - PENNIES;
                }
```

Comment: that worked wow i dont know why i didnt think of that, thank you

Comment: @mostateCB If this answer solved you problem, [you can accept this as the correct answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

You are already calculating the number of coins required with the code below:

```
int quarterVal = changeVal / QUARTERS;
etc....
```

But you are then incrementing this by 1 if the changeVal is equal to one of your predefined constants.

Basically, you don't need the 4 if statements that increment the counts when the value entered is an exact match for one of your defined constants.